# Why do my servos jump to one side when i turn on the power supply?

Tags: servo

[image]

I have created a circuit with an Arduino Uno with a joystick, controlling two standard servos. I have connected these servos to a 5V power supply.

The problem is that often when I turn on the power supply, both servos turn completely to one side, clockwise. I then have to turn the servos back manually for the circuit to work.

How can I fix this problem?

Here is the code:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does you drive circuit look like? Obviously during power on it is driving the things.

Comment: What is a drive circuit? I don't know much since I'm quite new to this.

Comment: @ConstiWitzleben, Can you show how have you connected the servos to the Arduino. (circuit)?

Comment: And the code to drive the servo would help. Sounds like you might need to home them.

Comment: I have now edited the question and have included a picture of the circuit and the code

Comment: A picture doesn't add much clarity. You should add a circuit diagram. Edit your post and click the circuit diagram icon in the editor.

Comment: I have tried to do this, but I don't know how to find the symbol for a servo or some other things I have used.

Comment: Use a motor symbol for the servo. Show all the wires into the servo (maybe more than 2),

Comment: Your photo clearly shows the servos connected directly to the Arduino, so a circuit diagram is not required.

Comment: I tested your code on an Arduino Nano with various 'standard' servos. A few moved a bit at power on (which is normal for some brands), but all centered properly once the Arduino booted. What happens if you power a servo without connecting it to the Arduino?

Answer (score 1):

What is probably happening in when you power on, the Arduino takes time to reset and initialize the IO pin to the servo. As such the servo thinks it is getting a command. This is bad and can actually damage a cheaper servo.

You probably need a pull-down resistor on the servo line to keep it from getting a signal till the Arduino has a chance to initialize the IO pin.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTq865.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. What is a pull down resistor and how do I connect it though?

Comment: @ConstiWitzleben see edit

Comment: The wire you have drawn between the Arduino and teh Servo, is that the Signal Wire or the + Voltage wire?

Comment: @ConstiWitzleben signal....

Comment: I have made your suggested adjustments and they seemed to help at first, but I have now added another servo (also using your suggested pull-down resistor) and the problem has returned. Do you have any other idea on wht might be going wrong?

Comment: @ConstiWitzleben has to be related. Maybe bad connections, maybe slow software, impossible to tell remotely. You need to scope it out and see whats being sent to the servo and when.